# ng-model misbehaving with HTML reset method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Im trying to be as ellaborative as i can with my question....

**Scenario:**
I have three input fields in my html page Two of them are to accept user inputted values and the third one binds(adds) these two values.

**Done so far:**
I initially used `<input value="{{value1+value2}}" id="value3"/>` which took the values as string; solved this issue by substracting the string by 0. But, this calculated values wont go off even using the reset button.

Then someone here on SOF told me to use `<input ng-model="(value1-0)+(value2-0)" id="value3"/>` which works, but i noticed that even though the values disapper visually the model still holds some value.

(When, i enter some value into the first input field, the third calculated field add the value of the inputted field with the previous value of the second input field(value that the second field had previous to the reset)

**NOTE:**
Reset method resets the values of the first two user inputted fields, but not that of the third calcualtion field while using `<input value="{{value1+value2}}" id="value3"/>` OR `<input ng-bind="value1+value2" id="value3"/>`

While, when using `<input ng-model="(value1-0)+(value2-0)" id="value3"/>` the calculated field is visually cleared but when i enter some value into one of the user inputted fields(value1 or value2) the calculated field adds the entered number with the previous number that the field ccontained.

I tried many ways to solve this issue, but with no suuccess.... can someone please guide me through?

*Thanks in advance*.....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Snsa90/bnd40se5/) . Follow the link and take a look.

Basically, to have only number values in the user inputed fields, I used HTML5 number inputs, readily available in any newer browser.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="value1" />
  <input type="number" ng-model="value2" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="value1 + value2" />
  <button type="button" ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
</div>
```

And as for the javascript, here is my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.value1 = '';
  $scope.value2 = '';
  $scope.value3 = '';

  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.value1 = '';
    $scope.value2 = '';
    $scope.value3 = '';
  };
}
```

The three values are first initialized as empty strings, and on ng-click of the RESET button, they are nullified again.

**NOTE:** For the sake of simplicity I used number inputs instead of trying to implement some kind of javascript validation which I would suggest for production level. The point of my answer was just to explain the principle using the most basic concepts.